# How to embed youtube channel like a thumbnail gallery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, youtube

YouTube offers a channel embed code that displays it like a one-video-at-time widget where you can go to next and previous video. I would like to embed my channel on my website like a gallery of video thumbnails below the video. So that users sees all videos and can play any of it in the window above if he clicks it.

I have only URL of the channel for example youtube.com/abc, and want convert it to the widget mentioned above. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the URL:**http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/%5BChannel%20or%20User%5D/uploads** you will get a list of 25 newest videos in XML format for the specified user or channel. Just parse the xml and get the link to the thumbnail of videos and show them as a gallery with more option to load more videos. You can also fetch the video url to load the video in webView on thumbnail click.

For more analysis please check:

```
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Searching_for_Channels

and

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: hello, could you provide a sample with ID in URL?

Answer (score -1):

With GData API you will have to manually convert the feed into HTML.

You can use the **Youmax plugin** and specify your channel URL (or a playlist URL). Your Video Thumbnails will be converted to a nice Grid and can be played in the player above it like your requirement.

A small demo for your requirement - http://demos.codehandling.com/youmax_demo/youmax_inline_comment_button